# French pronunciation of « fête »

Tags: prononciation

I am getting confused on how to pronounce *fête*. I hear some people say *sete* and others say *fete*.
Which is the correct way of saying it?

Comment: Nobody pronounce it "sete".

Comment: Concerning the pronunciation of différent accents, i.e. "é", "è" and "ê", many french people say that the pronounciation is different and that, according to what you hear, you can deduce the accent on the word. As a french native speaker, I pronounce all accent the same and I never was able to identify the accent by hearing the word. In case of ambiguities between 2 possible accents, e.g. for "près" (near) and "prés" (meadows) , I only deduce the good orrthograph from the context.

Comment: @Graffito It really depend of your accent, I guess. The differences between « é » and « è » was obvious everywhere I lived, and both accents can't be interchanged, but it's probably not the case in the South, indeed.

Comment: @Graffito This is regional indeed. I regularly have a similar debate about the pronunciation of imperfect and simple past (e.g. _j'allais_ vs _j'allai_, which I don't pronounce the same but people from other parts of France can't tell apart when they speak).

Comment: Can you give an example of the *sete* pronunciation? I can't relate it to anything.

Comment: For what it's worth, confusing F and S [doesn't](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12048/10667) seem to be particularly uncommon.

Comment: Well, /f/ and /s/ are definitely opposable in French as shown by many minimal pairs (fa/sa, faux/saut, fût/su, fi/si, fou/sou, fait/sait, fée/ses) which does not warrant that they are easy to discriminate for non-native speakers or in degraded conditions for natives.

Comment: @GAMPUB: definitely; I would assume that it might only be a problem with some subset of non-native speakers (I've never run into this as a native English / Cantonese speaker) or in low quality conditions. (I've had people interpret an F over the phone as S, even in somewhat implausible circumstances.)

Comment: I understand why you've heard "set", because of the audio quality of computer's speakers.

Comment: Over the telephone, it is impossible to distinguish /f/ and /s/, because they only differ in high frequencies which are not carried on telephone lines. (The same is true for /v/ and /z/.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mainstream pronunciation is /**fɛt**/,
with a southern French accent, that might be /**fɛ:tə**/,
with some eastern French accents and Belgian ones, that might be /**fɛ:t**/ or /**fe:t**/,
and finally in Quebec, the *ê* normally becomes a diphthong or a long vowel so you might hear [**faɪ̯t**], [**faɛ̯t**], or [**fɛ:t**], the latter mostly in official settings. On the other hand, [**fɛt**] (with a short vowel) will always be interpreted a representing *fait* or *faite*, the p.p. of *faire*.

In any case, nobody pronounces it "**sete**".

Comment: Don't forget /fɛ:t/ in Belgium where /fɛt/ would be interpreted as "le fait". (/fe:t/ is sometimes heard but strongly stigmatized).

Comment: @Eauquidort done, thanks for the advice.

Comment: As it is, [faɪ̯t] "fête" and [fɛt] "fait" (as in <je l'ai FAIT>) are in phonological opposition, which means that /ê/ and /è/ are different phonemes in Quebec French. (Note: <fait> and <faite> have the same pronunciation in QF.)

Comment: @NouLa C'est un fait! (/se.tœ̃.fɛt/)

Comment: @Montéedelait Un fait divers ?

Comment: @jlliagre Pas celui-là, non. Le T du fait divers ne se prononce jamais (que je sache).

Comment: En fait /fɛt/, je voulais simplement mentionner que le nom fait /fɛ/ se prononce aussi, à l'occasion, comme le participe passé (féminin ou masculin) du verbe faire. Mais comme le montre le fait /fɛ/ divers que vous mentionâtes fort à propos, ce phénomène n'est pas systématique, et est même complètement exclus dans certains cas. Probablement digne d'une question séparée, en fait /fɛt/.

Comment: @Montéedelait Le fait est que je m'interroge sur la prononciation de *fait* au Québec suite au commentaire de Nou La qui indique que *fait* et *faite* s'y prononcent de manière identique.

Comment: @jlliagre Ce n'est pas systématique, mais en effet très commun que le participe passé au masculin ait son T prononcé. Les médias ne se font pas en général le relais de cette prononciation, mais les Québécois dans leur vaste majorité y sont exposés pour peu qu'ils se rendent occasionnellement au travail ou à l'école, ou même simplement à l'épicerie.

Answer (score 5):

The correct pronunciation is **`[fɛt]`**.

You can listen this in "Prononciation" section of [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%AAte#Prononciation).

Comment: Generally speaking, it's more useful to know whether a pronunciation is “standard” or “usual” rather than “good”. That's especially true in this case, since native speakers pronounce the word in different ways.

Comment: @Chop : You're right, I edited my post.

Answer (score 4):

I pronounce it the same as "faite", if you want it without the IPA.  My accent would be closest to Parisian. The "ê" is usually pronounced ɛ, like an e before double consonants for instance in chi**e**nne. 
Bonus: The origin of the circonflexe or "hat" accent in this case was the replacement of the s in the old french version "feste".  It's still there in other forms of the word.  For example, "des activités festives".  Frequently the accent denotes this deletion of another letter/sound, but this is not always the case.

Comment: +1 It’s interesting (?although maybe coincidental?) that your way of pronouncing it corresponds with the “faite” used in a circa 1050 example of its **Etymol**ogy et **Hist**ory (see [here near the bottom](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/f%C3%AAte)): «célébration **faite** à jour marqué». Your mention of the ‘missing’ “S” also makes me wonder if perhaps what @Tia27 really meant to say was: “I hear some people say fe**S**te” & that “I hear some people say **S**ete” was just a typo. As mentioned above in a comment, nobody pronounces it ‘sete,’ but perhaps some people [still] pronounce it ‘feste.’

Comment: Yeah that's what brought it to mind.  I've never heard it pronounced "feste" , but it makes more sense and seems more likely than "sete" which just leaves me with ???.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any native French speaker to say "feste" these days. Only  a Spanish, Portuguese, Italian, Catalan etc. native speaker might erroneously use that word en French.

Comment: The non-Gallo-Romance language varieties still spoken in and native to Southern France  have <festa> too. These language varieties belong to the same family as Catalan, Occitano-Romance, a subdivision of Ibero-Romance.

Answer (score 2):

It is consistently pronounced as "FET". Perhaps you had confused it with somebody saying one of the following: **cet**(s)**, cette**(s)**, or c'est**?